# disabled built in zoom controls disable pinch zoom, too

Tags: android, webview, zooming, gesture

I have a WebView which should support zoom. The UI design requires custom zoom controls and therefore I disabled the built in zoom controls. The problem now, the pinch zoom is disabled, too. Setting the built in controls enables the pinch zoom.

```
final WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false); // disables the pinch zoom, too
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
```

Does someone know a solution to disable/hide the built in controls and keep the pinch zoom?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it is a package deal. You'll have to re-implement pinch zooming your self I think. I could be wrong though.

Comment: hm... I just found out that this issue is on my Nexus One, but not on the Galaxy Tab, so there is some inconsistence implementation... it could be a android bug, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a function [setDisplayZoomControls](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDisplayZoomControls%28boolean%29),
Sets whether the on screen zoom buttons are used. A combination of built in zoom controls enabled and on screen zoom controls disabled allows for pinch to zoom to work without the on screen controls

**NOTE**: Since API Level 11 only:(